# Querying a second XML page with strings

Tags: php, xml

Would anyone be willing to help me figure out how I can retrieve the franchise name from the second XML page using the franchise id?

I am working with two different pages. The first page will get me a list of the franchise ids. I would like to be able to get the franchise name from the second XML page by using the franchise id from the first page.

Let me know if you need more information, in order to be able to help.

I am looking for an answer in PHP.

PHP: Parsing first XML page

```
$url = "XMLPAGEURL";
 $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
  foreach ($xml->franchise as $franchise) {
   echo ''.$franchise[id].'';
  }
```

Second XML page

```
<league id="1"/>
 <franchises count="5">
  <franchise name="A" id="0001"/>
  <franchise name="B" id="0002"/>
  <franchise name="C" id="0003"/>
  <franchise name="D" id="0004"/>
  <franchise name="E" id="0005"/>
 </franchises>
</league>
```

Comment: you have id and name in the second page, is there any need to process the first?

Comment: If I understand you good you want to intersect two xml files? Why don't u use 2 loops

Comment: on page 2 use the same method as page1 and construct an array of franchisees `$fanchisee[$franchise['id']]=$franchise['name'];` you can now use this to retrieve the name `$fanchisee['0001']` is `A`

Comment: you can load the data from XML1 into and array using id as the index, then do the same for XML2. then `array_merge_recursive` will push the data together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not nest your looping of both sets of data, as there would only be one match in the second set, for the current id of the first. Doing them separately and merging the data is the best solution

```
<?php
$data=array();

$url1 = "http://football99.myfantasyleague.com/2007/export?TYPE=standings&L=46184&XML=1";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url1);
foreach ($xml->franchise as $franchise)
{
    $id=(string) $franchise->attributes()->id;

    $data[$id]['id']=$id;
    foreach($franchise as $key=>$value)
    {
        $data[$id][$key]=(string) $value;
    }
}

$url2 = "http://football99.myfantasyleague.com/2007/export?TYPE=league&L=46184&XML=1";
$xml_second = simplexml_load_file($url2);
foreach($xml_second->franchises->franchise as $franchise_sec)
{
    //var_dump($franchise_sec);
    $id=(string) $franchise_sec->attributes()->id;
    foreach($franchise_sec->attributes() as $key=>$value)
    {
        $data[$id][$key]=(string) $value;
    }
}

print_r($data);
```

this puts the `id` in the data in the first loop and the `name` in the second loop, using id as the index on both (as this is the common element)
I've attempted to add some other data too

UPDATED as testing proved that changes to code were required

output generated was:-

```
Array
(
    [0009] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0009
            [h2hw] => 12
            [name] => Hindenberg
            [logo] => http://www99.myfantasyleague.com/fflnet2005/helmets/h-0051.gif
        )

    [0004] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0004
            [h2hw] => 9
            [name] => Skins
            [logo] => http://www99.myfantasyleague.com/fflnet2005/helmets/h-0837.gif
        )

    [0010] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0010
            [h2hw] => 9
            [name] => Marooned
            [logo] => http://www99.myfantasyleague.com/fflnet2005/helmets/h-0841.gif
        )

    [0003] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0003
            [h2hw] => 7
            [name] => Elf Boys
            [logo] => http://www99.myfantasyleague.com/fflnet2005/helmets/h-0703.gif
        )

    [0007] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0007
            [h2hw] => 7
            [name] => Juggernaut
            [logo] => http://www99.myfantasyleague.com/fflnet2005/helmets/h-0689.gif
        )

    [0006] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0006
            [h2hw] => 7
            [name] => Knights
            [logo] => http://www99.myfantasyleague.com/fflnet2005/helmets/h-0708.gif
        )

    [0002] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0002
            [h2hw] => 7
            [name] => Dr. Death
            [logo] => http://www99.myfantasyleague.com/fflnet2005/helmets/h-0829.gif
        )

    [0005] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0005
            [h2hw] => 6
            [name] => Busted Season
            [logo] => http://www99.myfantasyleague.com/fflnet2005/helmets/h-0842.gif
        )

    [0001] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0001
            [h2hw] => 4
            [name] => Deep Divot
            [logo] => http://www99.myfantasyleague.com/fflnet2005/helmets/h-0826.gif
        )

    [0008] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0008
            [h2hw] => 3
            [name] => Last Place
            [logo] => http://www99.myfantasyleague.com/fflnet2005/helmets/h-0827.gif
        )

)
```

You can retrieve the data as follows:-

```
while(list($key,$franchise)=each($data))
{
    echo $franchise['id'].': '.$franchise['name'].' <img src="'.$franchise['logo'].'"/><br />';
}
```

Comment: Thank you. When I used this I got this warning message: Illegal offset type in ... The illegal offset is occurring in 4 places. $data[$franchise['id']]['id']=$franchise['id']; $data[$franchise['id']]['h2hw']=$franchise->h2hw; $data[$franchise_sec->franchise['id']]['name']=$franchise_sec->franchise['name']; and $data[$franchise_sec->franchise['id']]['logo']=$franchise_sec->franchise['logo'];

Comment: Would you mind updating the script to show a way to echo the results, instead of printing them?

Comment: I've looped through the data and outputted the ID, NAME and LOGO